# List of extensions of filenames in bash script in one line

Tags: bash, sed, filenames, ls, tr

I currently have the following line of code:

```
ls /some/dir/prefix* | sed -e 's/prefix.//' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Which does achieve what I want it to do:

- Get list of files starting with prefix
- Remove path and prefix from each string
- Remove newlines and replace with spaces for later processing.

For example:

```
/some/dir/prefix.hello
/some/dir/prefix.world
```

Should become

```
hello world
```

But I feel like there's a nicer way of doing this. Is there a better way to do this in one line?

Comment: You seem to remove not just `prefix`, but also the next character. Is that what you want?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yeah the prefix and the ., I want the list of file extensions essentially.

Comment: So, a literal period, right?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes. I'll add some examples to the question

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Do you need to use the `ls` program, won't `echo` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a two-liner using just built-ins that does it:

```
fnames=(some/dir/prefix*)
echo "${fnames[@]##*.}"
```

And here's how this works:

- `fnames=(some/dir/prefix*)` creates an array with all the files starting with `prefix` and avoids all the problems that come with parsing `ls`
- `echo "${fnames[@]##*.}"` is a combination of two parameter expansions: `${fnames[@]}` prints all array elements, and the `##*.` part removes the longest match of anything that ends with `.` from each array element, leaving just the extension

If you're hell-bent on a one-liner, just join the two commands with `&&`.

Comment: Avoiding ls based on the advice here, and your solution is the more readable one so I'm marking this as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Very simple and nice.

Answer (score 1):

passing `ls` output to external programs is not recommended, following bash solution may help you here.

```
for file in prefix*; do echo ${file##*.}; done
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
for file in prefix*
do
   echo ${file##*.}
done
```

Comment: This prints a file per line, though, and would fail for something like `/path/.has/period/prefix.ext` because it removes the shortest match of `*.`.

Comment: @BenjaminW., thanks for letting me know, overlooked it, added it now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple Awk one-liner to achieve this :

```
awk -F. '{$0=FILENAME; printf $NF" "; nextfile}' /some/dir/prefix*
```

It essentially does the following :

- `-F.`: Set the field separator `FS` to a `.`. This way `$NF` represents the extension.
- `$0=FILENAME`: Ignore the current record and set it to `FILENAME`, reparse everything this way.
- `print $NF; nextfile` : print the extension and go to the next file.

The problem with this is that the file still reads a record of the current file. If that file is empty this will fail.

To make this work with empty files, you could use the `gawk` extension `BEGINFILE`

```
awk -F. 'BEGINFILE{$0=FILENAME; printf $NF" "; nextfile}' /some/dir/prefix*
```

Or you can loop over all the arguments :

```
awk -F. 'BEGIN{for(i in ARGV){$0=ARGV[i]; printf $NF" "};exit}' /some/dir/prefix*
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach with awk:

```
ls /some/dir/prefix* | awk -F"." '{printf "%s ", $2} END {print ""}'
```

It might qualify as being "nicer" because there's only one command the output is piped through?!

Comment: @Iubgr, honestly we shouldn't pass output of `ls` to external programs.

Comment: Lowering the number of piped commands was exactly what I was going for. I prefer Benjamins answer as it has better readability (IMO)